# I have a list of strings (html codes) and I want to extract all the emails in each of the string of my list

Tags: python, string, text

I have a list of strings:

```
urls = ["url1","url2","url3"]
```

in order to generate another list of strings:

```
for i in range (0,2):
    htmlist = [urllib.urlopen(url[i]).read() for i in range(0,2) ]
```

When I try to extract the emails from the texts htmlist[i] with this code:

```
for i in range (0,2) :
    emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', htmlist[i])
print emails
```

the code only print emails in `htmlist[2]`

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `emails` takes the value of the last iteration (at `htmlist[2]`). Move the print statement into the `for` loop to see `emails` at each iteration:

```
for i in range (0, 3) :
    emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', htmlist[i])
    print emails
```

---

More so, the first iteration does not require `range` since you already have a list comprehension. You only need to change the stop index to `3`, so you have `htmmlist[0]`, `htmmlist[1]` and `htmmlist[2]`:

```
htmlist = [urllib.urlopen(url[i]).read() for i in range(0,3)]
#                                                       ^
```

Using `range` only repeats the initial iteration for as long the for loop runs. `htmlist` will only the last value from the loop. So the list comprehension is sufficient.

---

You can also use a list comprehension to keep all the emails from each url in a list:

```
htmlist = [urllib.urlopen(url[i]).read() for i in range(0,3)]

emails = [re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', htmlist[i]) for i in range(0,3)]
print emails
```

Comment: Thank you Moses. Ok now it's better but it can only print: emails[0] and emails[1]. It looks like emails[2] is not taken. Indeed, if I try to print htmlist[2] it tell me "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @GiacomoBonvini change the stop value of range to `3`. You can use another list comprehension to keep all the emails in another list. See my updated answer

Comment: I fix it. It was my fault. I wrote print emails[i] instead of print emails. It works correctly.